# Where to put anchor tags in Angular CSR Applications such that routes get indexed?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, seo, googlebot

I built this site with Angular 10:

`https://fireflysemantics.com/`

And when the top level domain is visited it reroutes to this:

`https://fireflysemantics.com/welcome`

However There's no link to that from anywhere within the app, so I don't think Google has any way of indexing that page.

What would be the best way of telling Google to index the page.  From my research it seems I could do something like this:

```
<body>
  <a class="hidden" href="https://example.com/welcome" title="Welcome to example.com">Welcome to example!</a>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Thoughts?

Also any thoughts on the max number of links that this would work with and any other approaches?

Comment: There really isn’t anything in your index.html.. and that is the ONLY actual page there is. You’ll have to assume that the googlebot is not actually executing your javascript, so there simply is no content there. Your little ‘hack’ doesn’t actually do anything, it just serves the same (almost empty) index.html page. There are 2 solutions for this, SSR or Static Rendering. Static is my personal fav, especially for fairly simple sites that do not change a lot. I use Scully for this and it’s great!

Comment: @MikeOne I added the anchor tag `<a class="hidden" href="https://fireflysemantics.com/welcome" title="Welcome to Fireflysematnics.com">Welcome to Fireflys Semantics!</a>` directly to the body in `index.html` and it's hidden via a hidden class ... I'm not sure whether that's going to do the trick though (I think that's what you mean by little 'hack') ... I'm also planning on adding a site map to robot.txt ...

Comment: @MikeOne do you know if Scully generated pages can be served with Github Pages by chance?

Comment: Please don't cross post to different stack exchange sites.  When you do, we end up with duplicates